# Not able to clear Text area field using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to send some data to a textare field as follows:

```
txtBox_ReviewComment.sendKeys("a");
```

The locator of 'txtBox_ReviewComment' Webelement is `.//textarea[@id='comment']`(XPATH) and it is defined as shown below in the HTML.

```
<textarea id="comment" class="form-control" required="" aria-describedby="comment-validation-messages" rows="6" placeholder="Enter Comment" maxlength="600"/>
```

I tried to clear the text are field in different possible ways. but none of them are working.

1. ```
   txtBox_ReviewComment.sendKeys(" ");
   txtBox_ReviewComment.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);`
   ```
2. ```
   txtBox_ReviewComment.mouseHover();
   txtBox_ReviewComment.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
   txtBox_ReviewComment.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
   txtBox_ReviewComment.clear();`
   ```

Is there any other way i could clear the data in the textarea field.

Comment: Have you tried using "*" in your xpath instead of "textarea" ?  element.clear() is the proper way to clear a text input element.  Note that .clear() cannot be followed by sendKeys() on the same line (statement)

Comment: if there is id then why are u using xpath. have you tried like `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("comment"));
element.clear();
element.sendKeys("Text");`

Comment: @BillHileman: I tried '*' too. Didn't work. Let me try out other ways of identifying the element.

Comment: Check the HTML code to see if your textarea is inside an iFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `xpath` of the element is `.//textarea[@id='comment']`, try clearing the textbox with:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//textarea[@id='comment']")).clear();`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried that. But didn't work.

Comment: @SKondapalli Can you consider updating us the relevant HTML DOM so we can help you out? Thanks